# Android Copy a static array of objects from one Java class to another

Tags: java, android, mysql, arrays

I'm retrieving data from mysql, and creating Question objects from them.
I've made an array of Question objects. Now I want to access it from other Java Activities. When I try to get its throwing NullPointerException from the other class, but inside the instantiated class it shows that it is populated.

My code is:

Comment: `FetchData` won't finish instantly

Comment: How to finish it?

Comment: What's line 35 of QuizActivity class? Did you post the original version of QuizActivity.java?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

You need to make sure that the AsyncTask has finished its job after you've called it with `fetchData.execute();` by adding the necessary logic to the `onPostExecute(Void aVoid)` method of your FetchData class.